# What do "fairish man" & "rich complexion" mean in "The New Jersey Sphinx"?

Tags: meaning, short-stories, r-austin-freeman, dr-thorndyke

In "[The New Jersey Sphinx](https://archive.org/details/bluescarab00free/page/90/mode/2up)" in *Dr. Thorndyke's Case-Book* by R. Austin Freeman, Thorndyke went to a porter to know the vacant chambers to let, and asked him whether it's quiet:

> "Quiet?"
>
> "Yes, pretty quiet. There's a metallurgist overhead—Highley—used to be Burt & Highley, but Burt has gone to the City, and I don't think Highley does much business now."
>
> "Let me see," said Thorndyke, "I think I used to meet Highley sometimes—a tall, **dark man**, isn't he?"
>
> "No, that would be Burt. Highley is a little, **fairish man**, rather bald, with a pretty **rich complexion**"—here Mr. Larkin tapped his nose knowingly and raised his little finger—"which **may account for the falling off of business**."

I found that "fairish" may mean "blonde or light skinned", but what's the meaning of "rich complexion"?

Does it mean "**rich appearance**"? or "**vivid skin color**"?

And **why should that account for "falling of business"**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My interpretation of rich complexion (in this context) is flushed or red. This often a side effect of drinking or alcoholism and Larkin is implying that is the reason the business is failing.

Answer (score 3):

That he is a "fairish man" probably means that he is blond-haired and light-skinned. I absolutely agree with the answer by Paula that "rich complexion" here means "flushed, as if from habitual drinking". When the text says that:

> here Mr. Larkin tapped his nose knowingly and raised his little finger

the nose is stereotypically first to show a flush from overuse of alcohol, and the lifting of a little finger was then a standard gesture to indicate lifting a glass to drink from. The two together are almost a blatant way of saying "he drinks too much".